# Print only each character and number once

Tags: java, string

I want to not use HashMap or Set when printing Duplicate characters in a String. But in solution I'm using I'm printing all the characters even if they are duplicates. I want to print each character once and with number of times it occurs in the string. Here's my example:

```
  public static void printDups(String s1) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s1.length(); j++) {
            if (s1.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(j)) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(s1.charAt(i) + " --> " + count);

        count = 0;
    }
}
```

`public static void main(String[] args) { 
    printDups("AABBCCDDD){}
}`

And this is the output:

```
A --> 2
A --> 2
B --> 2
B --> 2
C --> 2
C --> 2
D --> 3
D --> 3
```

I want to print it like that:

```
A --> 2
B --> 2
C --> 2
D --> 3
```

I know I can add this: `if (s1.charAt(i) != s1.charAt(i+1))         System.out.println(s1.charAt(i) + " --> " + count);`
But then I'll have StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:

If I change my loop to this `for (int i = 0; i < s1.length()-1; i++)`

It'll skip the last character in the string.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: this is good for code golf: codegolf.stackexchange.com, not here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it belongs more to code golf

Comment: `s1.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(j)` this line will compare same character in string because of `i` and `j`, both contains same value. As a example in first iteration `i = 0` and `j = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this function, I added two lines in it

```
s1 = s1.replaceAll(s1.charAt(i) + "", "");
          i--;
```

in you existing function

```
public static void printDups(String s1) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s1.length(); j++) {
            if (s1.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(j)) {
                count++;
            }

        }

        System.out.println(s1.charAt(i) + " --> " + count);
        s1 = s1.replaceAll(s1.charAt(i) + "", "");
      i--;
        count = 0;
    }


}
```

Comment: Your solution works! But could you explain this two lines: s1 = s1.replaceAll(s1.charAt(i) + "", "");
      i--;

Comment: `s1.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(j)` this line will compare same character in string because of `i` and `j`, both contains same value. As a example in first iteration `i = 0` and `j = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can add this: if (s1.charAt(i) != s1.charAt(i+1))         System.out.println(s1.charAt(i) + " --> " + count); But then I'll have StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:

What you can do is add another condition to it so it does not go out of bounds.

`if ( s1.length() < (i+1) && s1.charAt(i) != s1.charAt(i+1))`

Comment: Doesn't print anything with this

Answer (score 0):

What about adding each printed character to a Set and checking before each print, if this set contains already the character to print.

```
public static String eliminateDups(final String s1) {
        final Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            final char c = s1.charAt(i);
            if (set.contains(c)) {
                // skip
            } else {
                sb.append(c);
            }
            set.add(c);

        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to use a HashMap or set, sorting the string before counting is a good option. Also, you are using a nested loop traversing the string twice, hence your time complexity is **O(N^2)** where N is the length of your string. While sorting the string first and then traversing it once reduces your time complexity to **O(NlogN)**.

*Note that using a HashMap would have made the time complexity **O(N)**.*

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PrintDuplicates
{
  public static void printDups(String str){

    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    String sorted = new String(chars);

    //to handle the edge case that the String is of 0 length
    if(sorted.length() == 0){
     return;
    }

    int count=1;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i< sorted.length()-1; i++){

      if(sorted.charAt(i) != sorted.charAt(i+1)){
      System.out.println(sorted.charAt(i)+"-->"+count);
      count = 1;
    }
    else{
      count++;
    }
  }

  System.out.println(sorted.charAt(i)+"-->"+count); //to print the last character and it's count last seen

  }
  public static void main(String[] args){

    // printDups("");
    // printDups("A");
    //printDups("ABA");
    printDups("ABCCAAADAA");
   }
}
```